# how to import csv file if it both includes delimiters / and ,

Tags: csv, sas

I have a file with mixed delimiters `,` and `/`. When I import it into SAS with the following data step:

```
data SASDATA.Publications ;
    infile 'R:/Lipeng_Wang/PATSTAT/Publications.csv' 
        DLM = ',' 
        DSD missover lrecl = 32767 
        firstobs = 3 ;
    input pat_publn_id :29. 
        publn_auth :$29. 
        publn_nr :$29. 
        publn_nr_original :$29. 
        publn_kind :$29. 
        appln_id :29. 
        publn_date :YYMMDD10. 
        publn_lg :$29. 
        publn_first_grant :29. 
        publn_claims :29. ;
    format publn_date :YYMMDDd10. ;
run ;
```

the sas log shows that

```
NOTE: Invalid data for appln_id in line 68262946 33-34.
NOTE: Invalid data for publn_date in line 68262946 36-44.
RULE:     ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9
 68262946  390735978,HK,1053433,09/465,054,A1,275562685,2010-03-26,  ,0,0 62
 pat_publn_id=390735978 publn_auth=HK publn_nr=1053433 publn_nr_original=09/465 publn_kind=054
 appln_id=. publn_date=. publn_lg=2010-03-26 publn_first_grant=. publn_claims=0 _ERROR_=1
 _N_=68262944
NOTE: Invalid data for appln_id in line 68280355 33-34.
NOTE: Invalid data for publn_date in line 68280355 36-44.
 68280355  390753387,HK,1092990,60/523,466,A1,275562719,2010-03-26,  ,0,0 62
 pat_publn_id=390753387 publn_auth=HK publn_nr=1092990 publn_nr_original=60/523 publn_kind=466
 appln_id=. publn_date=. publn_lg=2010-03-26 publn_first_grant=. publn_claims=0 _ERROR_=1
 _N_=68280353
```

it seems that i need to file '60/523,466' into the volume of 'publn_nr_original'. but what should I do for it?

Comment: What does the documentation say for that specific field? It is fairly unlikely that a well established database would have this type of issue, so I wonder if it's something else going on here.

Comment: Reformatting the code and better introducing the code. (But sorry, I still don't understand the objective)

Comment: THE prefered solution for this type of issue is to ask your data supplier to deliver consistently formtted data. Only if that is inpossible, proceed with repearing the issues created by others.

Comment: Please supply example data and tell us if the issue occurs for all data lines or not

Answer (score 1):

Your program code has two obvious issues.

First your syntax on the FORMAT statement is wrong.  The `:` modifier is a feature of the `INPUT` or `PUT` statement syntax and should not be used in a `FORMAT` statement.

Second you are trying to read 29 digits into a number. You cannot store 29 digits accurately into a number in SAS.  If those values are really longer than 15 digits you will need to read them into character variables. And if they really are smaller numbers (that could be stored as numbers) then you don't need to include an informat specification to the `INPUT` statement. SAS already knows how to read numbers from text files.  In list mode the INPUT statement will ignore the width on the informat anyway.

But your error message looks to be caused by an improperly formed file.  I suspect that one of the first 6 columns has a comma in its value, but whoever created the data file forgot to add quotes around the value with the comma.  If you can figure out which field the comma should be in then you might be able to parse the line in a way that it can be used.

Here is one method that might work assuming that the commas only appear in the `publn_nr_original` variable and that at most one comma will appear.

```
data want ; 
 infile cards dsd truncover firstobs=3;
 length
 pat_publn_id $30
 publn_auth $30
 publn_nr $30
 publn_nr_original $30
 publn_kind $30
 appln_id $30
 publn_date 8
 publn_lg $30
 publn_first_grant $30
 publn_claims $30
;
 informat publn_date YYMMDD10. ;
 format publn_date YYMMDDd10. ;
 input @;
 if countw(_infile_,',','mq')<= 10 then input pat_publn_id -- publn_claims ;
 else do ;
   list ;
   input pat_publn_id -- publn_nr_original xxx :$30. publn_kind -- publn_claims ;
   publn_nr_original=catx(',',publn_nr_original,xxx);
   drop xxx;
 end;
cards4;
Header1
Header2
1,22,333,4444,55,6666,2010-03-26,77,8,9999
390735978,HK,1053433,09/465,054,A1,275562685,2010-03-26,  ,0,0
390735978,HK,1053433,"09/465,054",A1,275562685,2010-03-26,  ,0,0
390753387,HK,1092990,60/523,466,A1,275562719,2010-03-26,  ,0,0
;;;;
```

But the real solution is to fix the process that created the file.  So instead of having a line like this in the file:

```
390735978,HK,1053433,09/465,054,A1,275562685,2010-03-26,  ,0,0
```

The line should have looked like this:

```
390735978,HK,1053433,"09/465,054",A1,275562685,2010-03-26,  ,0,0
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see what you mean - you have a field with a comma, in a comma separated file, and that field is not quoted.

For this you will have to read the two parts in seperately and add the comma back in, as per example code below.

It's worth noting that all your values must have commas for this approach to work!  This in fact looks like bad data, if your input field is indeed "60/523,466" then it should be "quoted" in your input file to be read in correctly.

```
%let some_csv=%sysfunc(pathname(work))/some.csv;
data _null_;
  file "&some_csv";
  put /;
  put '390735978,HK,1053433,09/465,054,A1,275562685,2010-03-26,  ,0,0';
  put '390753387,HK,1092990,60/523,466,A1,275562719,2010-03-26,  ,0,0';
run;


data work.Publications ;
  infile "&some_csv" DLM = ',' DSD missover lrecl = 32767 firstobs = 3 ;
  input pat_publn_id :best. publn_auth :$29. publn_nr :$29. 
    publn_nr_original1 :$29. publn_nr_original2:$29. 
    publn_kind :$29. appln_id :best. 
    publn_date :YYMMDD10. publn_lg :$29. publn_first_grant :best. 
    publn_claims :best. ;
  format publn_date YYMMDDd10. ;
  publn_nr_original=cats(publn_nr_original1,',',publn_nr_original2);
run ;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I confirm A1 is a variable belong to publn_kind,. besides, appln_id is a numeric in terms of the Data Catalog shows that Domain of appln_id is Number 0 … 999 999 999. therefore, it seems that i need to file '60/523,466' into the volume of 'publn_nr_original'. but what should I do for it?

Comment: I updated (made `appln_id` numeric once more).  The approach above places A1 into `publn_kind`, and puts both parts of the variable into `publn_nr_original`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but '09/465,054' are separated into two parts, which are '60/523' and '466' and separately put into volume ’publn_nr_original1' and volume 'publn_nr_original2'.